# GD installed in docker but imagecreatetruecolor doesn't exist

Tags: php, docker

Another issue with docker, i have installed php gd and i can see it in phpinfo yet when i try to use imagecreatetruecolor it doesn't seem to exist.

I am building dockerfile like this:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt update

RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev zip curl libpng-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip gd mbstring

RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql zip gd

RUN apt -y install bash

RUN apt -y install procps

RUN apt -y install iputils-ping

RUN apt -y install vim

# make sure www-data has correct uid and gid
RUN usermod --uid 1001 www-data
RUN groupmod --gid 1001 www-data

COPY ./docker/php-backend/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php.ini

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o /tmp/composer-setup.php

RUN php /tmp/composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN rm -f composer-setup.php

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN mkdir bin && mkdir config && mkdir public && mkdir src && mkdir templates && mkdir var && mkdir var/log && mkdir var/cache

COPY ./api/bin/ ./bin/
COPY ./api/config/ ./config/
COPY ./api/public/ ./public/
COPY ./api/src/ ./src/
COPY ./api/templates/ ./templates/
COPY ./api/composer.json .
COPY ./api/composer.lock .
COPY ./api/symfony.lock .

RUN composer install

RUN rm composer.json composer.lock symfony.lock

RUN rm /usr/local/bin/composer
```

phpinfo:

> GD Support    enabled GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible) GIF Read
> Support   enabled GIF Create Support  enabled PNG Support enabled libPNG
> Version   1.6.37 WBMP Support enabled XBM Support enabled BMP
> Support   enabled TGA Read Support    enabled

I'm simply running an if to check if the function exists

```
// check to see if GD function exist
if(!function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')) {
    $error = "GD Library Error: imagecreatetruecolor does not exist";
    die( $error );
}
```

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same, let me know if you found a solution